# What is better way of arranging filters?

Tags: filter

I would like to have your opinion on the [image]arranging of filters when presented on top of the page.
Option 1 - Arranging fields top to bottom 
Option 2- Arranging fields left to right
or any better option?

Comment: What there is a drop-down? Can you tell what option is available under each filter?

Comment: Dropdown would have a list of items (single selection).Like geography. Which prompts another question, what if there is multi section required?

Comment: Could you tell options available apart from geography?

Comment: other examples, report type, generated on, modified by etc.

Comment: Are they dependent?

Comment: not all but there is a possibility.

Comment: I think this design was much bigger issues then the way how you pivot dropdowns.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the convention is we read left to right in a Z pattern in the West, option 1 seems clearer. Perhaps it's because the labels and fields line up nicely.

12 filters... could these be added to in the future (dread the thought)? Are they all valid? Could some become invalid, depending on a previously selected filter value?

Comment: yes, there can be even more than 12 filters on some screens, mostly they are independent but in some scenarios, one filter may depend on another.for example, a county on geography selected but that's a rare case.

Comment: I agree with Z pattern but there is an unnecessary space on both sides in option 2, which doesn't look good.Any suggestions to deal with that?

Comment: Is it possible to return to your use cases and information architecture, these seem over the top, in the real world, what are the most commonly used filters by your team?

Comment: so, we have multiple screens in line with this format with a different set of important filters, for eg. on report screen few important filters can be 'report type, generate (monthly,annually etc), modified by, created on , created by , geography, country, region, business type' etc.

Comment: As stated, for me option 1 is clearer, I think there's a case to look at how your users use the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize your filters. An example is shown below.

If a user selects geography than in country filter only countries belonging to that geography would be visible. Same case applicable for state & city filter.

Let me know if this helps.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvBkjE.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: yes, currently it is happening this way only.The primary concern I am facing is regarding grouping of these filters.Left to right or top to bottom.Thanks!